# How to print all the flags passed to a go program?

Tags: go

I would like to log all the flags(cmdline args) passed to a program at startup. How do I do this? Currently the program uses `flag` package to read the flags into the program .

Comment: If it's for logging, why not just log the raw arguments?

Comment: Hi @JimB. How do I do that? I want dump of the args passed to the program.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using the [flag](https://golang.org/pkg/flag) package, there is the concept of a "flag" which is a defined command line argument i.e.

```
name := flag.String("name", "default", "some name")
```

And also the concept of an "arg" which is an undefined command line argument (i.e. not a flag).

You can get the list of args with `flag.Args()` which returns `string[]`.

There doesn't seem to be a way to get the list of flags. There are `Visit` functions. You could use `VisitAll` that takes a function to execute on each flag:

```
flag.VisitAll(func(f *flag.Flag) {
    fmt.Printf("%s: %s\n", f.Name, f.Value)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `os.Args`, which is a slice of strings, from the `os` package.

E.g:

```
package main

import (
        "log"
        "os"
)

func main() {
        log.Println(os.Args)
}
```